# Approaches to make Node js-Express Rest api from mysql secure/Authenticate

Tags: node.js, express

I have used Express nodejs to Create Rest API from Mysql which will be **invoked by an front end javascript application**.
As the Rest service that are created is open I need some approach to authenticate such as passing username/token

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Could use `jwt tokens` for authentication.

You can look at this example on scotch.io [jwt auth](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens)

hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the response the article suggests the authentication with backend as mongo but as a beginner and with mysql as a backend for me could you share some links with mysql with express authentication

Comment: please take look at this https://vivavivugeek.blogspot.com/2016/09/build-jwt-authentication-server-with.html